# configure japid with play app?

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I want to use japid-0.9* with my new play application. I already installed japid for my exixtng application. i followed all step of configuration of japid.

1. make  change in application.conf file.
2. add japid jars in class path.

but still I can't find japid when I open it in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line

`- play -> japid 0.9.3.4`

to your conf/dependencies.yml

Run `play install; play eclipsify`

Finally refresh your project in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure once you have set up Japid as a dependency, you run `play eclipsify` again to make sure all the new settings are set up.

Comment: how can i set up Japid as a dependency, dependency?

Comment: probably badly worded. Japid uses the old module installation method, over ivy dependency management...so, once you have configured the module, then run `play eclipsify`